# Contraction on 3x3 matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-norms

I would like to prove that the following linear map is a contraction on the $3 \times 3$ complex matrices endowed with the usual operator norm (i.e. the largest singular value norm):
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
           a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
    a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} 
\end{pmatrix}
 \mapsto {2\over 3}\begin{pmatrix}
           a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
    a_{31} & a_{32} & {a_{11} + a_{22} \over 2}
\end{pmatrix}. $$

Numerical simulation shows this is likely to be true, but it is absolutely not clear to me how to prove it. Any idea is welcomed.